# Compilation error returning generic list with extending from a type

Tags: java, generics

Im implementing a generic adapted that access a master data repository and should be able to return a subtype of a Generic master data type, Implemented type representing broader master data type

```
public abstract class TypedMasterData implements Comparable<TypedMasterData> {
 .....
}
```

The specific type extends the master type

```
public class CompanyName extends TypedMasterData {
...
}
```

I have an adapter that abstracts accessing master data repo and should return the narrowed down type.

```
public class DefaultMasterDataRespositoryAdapter implements MasterDataRespositoryAdapter {

    //some code just to check for implementaion validity, 
    @Override
    public <T extends TypedMasterData> List<T> getAllValuesOfType(T t) {
        return Arrays.asList(new CompanyName[] {new CompanyName(1, "CompanyName", "ADLC", "ADLC", null)});
    }

    ....
}
```

but the method `getAllValuesOfType` gives a compilation error as below,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confuse about Generics here. I think a better implementation of `MasterDataRespositoryAdapter.getAllValuesOfType` would be:

```
public <T extends TypedMasterData> List<TypedMasterData> getAllValuesOfType(T t) ;
```

Although we don't know what the parameter `T t` is doing here so may be you can get rid of it.

You can think of `<T extends TypedMasterData>` as a concrete class that is at least of type `TypedMasterData` but here, you are trying to fit some `CompanyName` into a `List` of "concrete class". It is like trying to put some `Integer` into a `List<Double>`. Both `Integer` and `Double` inherits `Number` but that wont compile anyway. The workaround is to put `Integer` and `Double` into a `List<Number>`.

Generic are pretty difficult to handle. I myself still struggling with them sometimes, despite year of experience in Java.